# Scraping a HTTPs website with php

Tags: php, html, curl

I am trying to scrape a secure website. The website changes the data I am trying to scrape every day. This is my code:

```
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.website.com/DisplayData/?field1=1234'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$data = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
```

When I look at what is in `$data`, I see the HTML code, but it does not have any value. Here is a simplified version of what I get.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <table>
            </tr>
            <tr class="Table1">
                <td class="first-col">Table1</td>
                <td id="item1">--</td>
                <td id="item2">--</td>
                <td id="item3">--</td>
                <td id="item4">--</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

I go to the website using Chrome and use the development tools. There should be data in the table where the '--'s are. I inferred that the website has some kind of script that adds the values when a browser goes to the page. Is there a way to use cURL to get the website with the data I want?

Answer (score 0):

In short, no. cURL doesn't execute JavaScript on pages it requests. You would need something that does. Consider something like [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) or [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/).<sup>*</sup>

In any case, you're probably going about this the wrong way (see the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/238426)). Rather than scraping the site (which may violate the site's terms and is technically complex, in any case), why not see if the site offers an API or data feed of some sort?

<sup>* Disclaimer: I have no affiliation with these projects.</sup>

Comment: looking for an API was the first thing I looked for